# What does negative log likelihood of logistic regression in theano look like?

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, logistic-regression, deep-learning

I have been reading the [theano's logistic regression tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html). I was trying to understand how the [negative log likelihood](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#defining-a-loss-function) is calculated.

```
y = ivector('y')
W = dmatrix('W')
b = dvector('b')
input = dmatrix('inp')
p_y_given_x = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input, W) + b)
logs = T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y]
```

On pretty printing printing `theano.printing.pprint(logs)` it returned

```
'AdvancedSubtensor(log(Softmax(x)), ARange(TensorConstant{0}, Constant{0}[Shape(y)], TensorConstant{1}), y)'
```

Can anyone explain what is this `AdvanceSubtensor` doing with a minuscule example?

After this they calculated the `-T.mean(logs)`

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Your variable `logs` is a Theano symbolic expression. How it exactly `repr`s to the screen isn't important. They are placeholders and functions of `y, W, b`. As soon as you compile a function with these as arguments, you will be able to recover the values of `logs` as a function of them.

Comment: I just want a clarification on the shape of `logs`. Lets say `y` is an `n` size vector, `W` is a `n_features * n_classes` size matrix, `b` is a `n_classes` size vector and `input` is a `n * n_features` size input data matrix. Now, according to my understanding `p_y_given_x` is of size `n * n_classes`, assuming `b` will be broadcasted on each row after `T.dot(input, W)`. If I'm wrong in any of the above parts then correct me and I want to know the shape of `logs` in terms of these parameters.

Comment: `logs.shape` is equal to `y.shape` which is `n`: You are indexing into the array `p_y_given_x` which is of shape `(n, n_classes)` and you are picking out one entry per line, collapsing the `n_classes` axis and leaving just the `n` axis.

Comment: Thank you!! I got my answer... now when I look back I feel it was a dumb question :P One last question. Since I'm new to numpy and theano is this type of array indexing `some_double_dimensional_array[some_1d_array, another_1d_array_of_same_size]` possible in numpy also?

Comment: Yes, it is. Check out the broadcasting section of the numpy docs for all the other interesting constellations, too.