# Broadcasting of shared variables in logistic regression with theano

Tags: theano

I am currently going through the theano [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#logreg) for logistic regression, very much like discussed in this post:
[what-does-negative-log-likelihood-of-logistic-regression-in-theano-look-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921847/what-does-negative-log-likelihood-of-logistic-regression-in-theano-look-like). However, the original [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#logreg) uses **shared variables** W and b, as well as a matrix called *input*. Input is a `n x n_in` matrix, W is `n_in x n_out` and b is a `n_out x 1` column vector.

```
    self.W = theano.shared(
        value=numpy.zeros(
            (n_in, n_out),
            dtype=theano.config.floatX
        ),
        name='W',
        borrow=True
    )

    self.b = theano.shared(
        value=numpy.zeros(
            (n_out,),
            dtype=theano.config.floatX
        ),
        name='b',
        borrow=True
    )

    self.p_y_given_x = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input, self.W) + self.b)
```

Now, as far as I understood from the documentation of shared variables, the broadcasting pattern of shared variables defaults to false. So why is it that this line of code does not throw an error because of mismatched dimensions?

```
self.p_y_given_x = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input, self.W) + self.b)
```

After all, we are adding a matrix `T.dot(input, self.W)` to a vector `b`. Do shared variables broadcast by default after all? Even with broadcasting, the dimension don't add up. `T.dot(input, self.W)` is `n x n_out` matrix and b a `n_out x 1` vector.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared variables are not broadcastable by default as their shape can change, however, Theano takes care of necessary broadcasting with Tensors when operations like adding scalar to a matrix, adding vector to a matrix etc. are requested. Check the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#libdoc-tensor-broadcastable) for more details.
Note that `input` is a symbolic variable not a shared variable. The dimension mismatch would have occurred if second dimension of `self.W` i.e *n_out* would be different from first dimension of vector `b`, which is not the case here, so they perfectly add up, it's the same in numpy as well:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
b = np.asarray([1,2,3])
print(a + b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, there is still one detail I am missing: `self.b` is a shared variable and it is added to `T.dot(input, self.W)`. Hence it seems we need broadcasting to make this work, however `self.b` was not defined as broadcastable. Why does it work anyway? I understand why it would works with symbolic variables or in pure numpy, but not why it works with shared variables.

Comment: Because `T.dot(input, self.W)` will return symbolic matrix/vector. [theano.tensor.dot(X, Y)](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.dot)

Comment: Ok, with your help I found my mistake. It made click when I read this in theano's [docu](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html): _When two arguments to an element-wise operation (like addition or subtraction) have a different number of dimensions, the broadcastable pattern is expanded to the left, by padding with True_. So, assuming that at runtime this also holds for shared variables, which by default have a broadcastable pattern `[false, false, ...]`, all makes sense now. My mistake was to assume that padding does not happen for shared variables. Thank you!